Is QHE the only topological order up to 3D?
At the section II.C in this review paper about topological superconductors, the author states that

The symmetry of the Hamiltonian plays a crucial role in determining the topology of the occupied states. Actually, if no symmetry is assumed, the only possible topological phase in up to three dimensions is the quantum Hall state with a nonzero Chern number.

My question is: what exactly did the author mean by that? As far as I know, the notion of topological order does not depend in any way on symmetries. Furthermore, since he is not talking about SPT (since IQHE is LRE), the statement seems to imply that the only topological order up to 3D is the quantum hall phase. Is that right?

This review seems to be entirely about topological superconductors, so it is not surprising that their notion of topology is all about free fermion band topology (i.e. the ten fold way). The statement then is just that class A has nontrivial states only in even spatial dimensions, and below 3 diensions it's just integer quantum Hall.

There is a long-standing confusion in terminology regarding symmetries as applicable to first-quantized and second-quantized Hamiltonians. See this  discussion on Physics overflow: https://physicsoverflow.org/40756/symmetries-corresponding-altland-zirnbauer-symmetry-classes

The symmetry of the Hamiltonian determines which topological phases are possible for a specific dimension. Generally, three symmetries are important: time-reversal symmetry, particle-hole symmetry and chiral symmetry. Based on these three symmetries the Hamiltonian can be assigned to a certain 'class'. When the Hamiltonian lacks all three symmetries, the Hamiltonian belongs to class A.
In this specific class, based on the symmetry arguments, a topological band structure can only emerge in 2 dimensions. The physical realization of this topological phase is the quantum Hall effect.
The different topological classes are summarized in the 'periodic table of topological invariant' and gives an overview of all topological classed and the corresponding opological invariants for a certain dimension. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table_of_topological_invariants
